# Netsparker Detected Weak Ciphers Enabled. Is This Possible Although There Is No SSL Encryption?

Tags: encryption, web-application-security

I've scanned a web application with Netsparker. Although there is no https support on the site, Netsparker detected that weak ciphers are enabled. I know Netsparker says the scanner is false positive free; but is it possible to enable weak ciphers, even though encryption is not done on the site?